# Load view hierarchy dump xml file to Android Studio Layout Inspector in offline

Tags: android, android-studio, layout-inspector

I dumped hierarchy view of my app via command `adb shell uiautomator dump`. Now I have a dump file `window_dump.xml`. How can I view this dump file in **layout inspector** in Android Studio? Is that possible in some way? My goal is to check representation and attributes of some views properly. The view hierarchy I got is really difficult to read and understand, coordinates are written in `bounds` parameter, it is difficult to analyze this dump in the basic reading mode of this file.

Comment: i don't have much experience with this, but are you sure that the result of `adb shell uiautomator dump` is in any way actually compatible or related to the layout inspector ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody, i don't know that, i can't find this options here in layout inspector UI. Maybe it is really incompatible, but I want make it compatible, I can do view hierarchy dump in any other compatible with Layout Inspector way. Main goal is to load dump file (of any format) in Layout Inspector **offline**.